# Why does my old commits re-appear every time I update the changelog?

Tags: git, npm, npm-scripts, changelog

I am using the [conventional-changelog-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conventional-changelog-cli) and I want to update my Changelog with my newest version (2.3.2).

But when I run the `npm run changelog` script, random old commits get added into the new version - why is that?

*This is how my changelog should look after running `npm run changelog`:*

```
2.3.2 (2019-07-19)
- Bug Fixes
- Customer info is now available and presented for new customers as well. (16ec727)
- Exclude return from new savings graph calculations (39e5a60)
- Policy is calculated more accurate in graph (15985fd)

Features
- Add build number to version number (in parentheses) under 'About app' (9ae985a)
- Build- and version number added to NINAA and Demo app (fff7962)
```

*And this is how it actually looks:*

```
2.3.2 (2019-07-19)
Bug Fixes
- Add condition for biometrics pop-up after NemID, if creating new user (0d226b6)
- Added native pop-up for enable biometrics in settings and onboarding (86d3773)
- Android splash screen is no longer stretched (28f9f4a)
- changed critical illness link and made error message better (a0d86fd)
- Changed new bonus features, to match new API (77e4c8e)
- changed rxjs & rxjs-combat to v6.2.1 (c38f216)
- Policy is calculated more accurate in graph (15985fd)
- Add build number to version number (in parentheses) under 'About app' (9ae985a)
- app version number is now visible under 'About app' in the menu (b46df6c)
- Bonus has been moved to disbursement page (50e92b0)
- Build- and version number added to NINAA and Demo app (fff7962)
- Change the welcome page and intro onboarding page with new text and design (3139790)
- Prompt user to activate biometrics login, if is not enabled, but the device supports it (7f4c5b3)
- SSL certificate error is now handled in the app with "update app" page (91c7329)
Reverts
- Contact-info notification removed (333e655)
- density removed from Android phones (c4ac51a)
- Face ID authentication is not yet supported on Android. Code reverted. (875771d)
```

All theese commits are OLD and are already represented further dwówn in their respected version. Why are they reappearing?

My script in package.json looks like this: `"changelog": "conventional-changelog -p angular -i CHANGELOG.md -s -r && git add CHANGELOG.md"` and I also have a `.npmrc` file with `git-tag-version = false`.

I have searched the internet, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong?

I have tried to fetch my latest tags (using `git tag -l), and they look like this:

```
Build-v.-2.2.0.5
Build-v.-2.3.0.5
Build-v.2.2.0.4
Release-v.-2.2.0
Release-v.-2.3.0
Release-v.-2.3.0.5
Release-v.-2.3.1
v2.1.0-in-test-environments
```

My latest tag should therefore be 2.3.1, but when I run the `changelog` script, it compares the changes to `v2.1.0-in-test-environments` tag.

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `-r` flag. If you look closely at the docs it says using this `WILL overwrite"

https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog/tree/master/packages/conventional-changelog-cli#quick-start